# How to Cancel/Remove Redirecting the Client with Server side swift in perfect framework

Tags: ios, redirect, swift3, perfect, server-side-swift

In My Serverside swift demo, I have Redirecting to the Client. It's moved permenantly. How can I cancel redirection. I have used below code to redirect request.

```
response.status = .movedPermanently
response.setHeader(.location, value: "http://www.perfect.org/")
response.completed()
```

Right now i am not able to cancel or not call another function.
Is there any way to remove redirect request?

Answer (score 1):

the PerfectTemplate project:  https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git has already demonstrated your case:
https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate/blob/master/Sources/main.swift#L73

```
"routes":[
            ["method":"get", "uri":"/**", 
            "handler":PerfectHTTPServer.HTTPHandler.redirect,
             "base":"http://localhost:\(port1)"]
        ]
```

which means that all requests upon the the current server will be forwarded to the base url.